# fullCalendar - Properties not being applied on first load

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have started looking at the fullCalendar package but am seeing some unusual behavior when I first load.

I have it setup as follows:

```
<div id='calendar'></div>

<script>
        // Create FullCalendar Object
        $j('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            height: 650,
            nowIndicator: true,
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            columnHeaderFormat: 'ddd D MMM',
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            businessHours: businessHours,
            selectable: true,
            select: function (startDate, endDate) {
                AddWorkHours(startDate, endDate);
            }
        });

</script>
```

However when I first launch the calendar it appears as follows:

[image]

Where some of the properties do not appear to have been fully implemented:

1. Height seems to be being ignored.
2. Now Indicator is visible, but is stuck at the first moment of the current day.
3. Business Hours only seem to show in all-day, none of the times are shown.

The rest of the properties seem to have been picked up.
The strange thing then however is that if I navigate to the previous week (or any other place in fullCalender, it then renders correctly as follows:

[image]

Has anyone else experienced this behavior or have any suggestions on where to start looking. I am trying to implement this on quite a large system but am pretty sure I have all my JQuery loading before the fullCalendar.js file.

Comment: Do you have the div that the calendar is in, in any form of delayed reveal? I have a similar problem and have narrowed it down to that.

Answer (score 1):

do you have moment.js loaded before fullcalendar.js?
and check the versions are compatible.

the code snippet you have is working fine, I need to take a look at the businessHours var and AddWorkHours function to confirm that everything is fine.

if you check the example below you will see highlighted area (Monday - Friday start at 10AM to 6PM) that's the business hours in the example.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var businessHours = {
    // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
    dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], // Monday - Friday
    start: '10:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
    end: '18:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
  };
  
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height: 666,
    nowIndicator: true,
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    columnHeaderFormat: 'ddd D MMM',
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    businessHours: businessHours,
    selectable: true,
    select: function (startDate, endDate) {
      AddWorkHours(startDate, endDate);
    }
  });
  
  function AddWorkHours(startDate, endDate){
    alert('Selected Start Time is: ' + startDate);
    alert('Selected End Time is: ' + endDate);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<div id="calendar-container">
  <div id="calendar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ali. Just a few responses... I still get the same problem if I take out the businessHours & the call to my function, so am confident they have no impact on the problem. From what I can see I have loaded both JQuery & Moment before the fullCalendar.js files. I am trying to get this rendering in a partial MVC view so am wondering if that has something to do with anything? The versions I am using were already installed on the project I am working on: (JQuery: 2.0.3 & Moment: 2.9.0) - that could potentially be an issue but I havent seen a compatibility chart anywhere?

Comment: Plus the strange part is that it seems to all kick in once I navigate - as if it is issuing a re-rendering or something?

Comment: are you showing and hiding the calendar dynamically, like is it in a tab or popup window ??

Comment: I am not, no... It is just sat there on a partial view :o/

Comment: Try to run this function on load

$(window).load(function(){
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
});

Comment: I will give that a go now.. I have just found that my versions above should be compatible so don't think that is the problem. I will try this refresh and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I have added that suggestion in to my document.ready call - after the fullCalander is created and still no luck. Again, the page renders fine once I click to go elsewhere in the calendar. Have I put this code in the correct place?